# XSLT - looping in template using mode

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a sample xsl like this,

```
<doc>
    <p type="para">aaxx</p>
    <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
    <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
    <context type="para">aaxx</context>
    <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
    <s>jksjdl</s>
    <p type="para">bbcc</p>
    <p type="paraX">kkll</p>
    <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
    <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
    <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
    <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
    <k>text</k>
    <p type="para">bbcc</p>
    <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
    <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
    <context type="para">aaxx</context>
    <p type="paraX">kkll</p>
    <t>text</t>
    <p type="paraX">aa</p>
    <p type="paraX">kddkll</p>
</doc>
```

My requirment is,

search for any `<p type="para">` followed by any combination of `p` with a type starting with `paraX` and of `<context type="para”>` and insert that content into a `<section>`.

So, My expected output should look like,

```
<doc>
    <section>
        <p type="para">aaxx</p>
        <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
        <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
        <context type="para">aaxx</context>
        <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
    </section>
    <s>jksjdl</s>
    <section>
        <p type="para">bbcc</p>
        <p type="paraX">kkll</p>
        <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
        <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
        <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
        <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
    </section>
    <k>text</k>
    <section>
        <p type="para">bbcc</p>
        <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
        <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
        <context type="para">aaxx</context>
        <p type="paraX">kkll</p>
    </section>
    <t>text</t>
    <p type="paraX">aa</p>
    <p type="paraX">kddkll</p>
</doc>
```

I've written following XSLT to do that,

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[@type='para']"/>

    <xsl:template match="p[@type='paraX']"/>

    <xsl:template match="p[@type='para']">
        <section>
            <p type="para">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="box"/>
        </section>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p" mode="box">
        <p type="{@type}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::p[1][@type='paraX'] | following-sibling::context[1][@type='para']" mode="box"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="context" mode="box">
        <context type="{@type}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </context>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::p[1][@type='paraX'] | following-sibling::context[1][@type='para']" mode="box"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

But it gives the following output,

```
<doc>
    <section>
        <p type="para">aaxx</p>
        <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
        <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
        <context type="para">aaxx</context>
        <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
        <context type="para">aaxx</context>
        <p type="paraX">kkll</p>
        <context type="para">aaxx</context>
        <p type="paraX">kkll</p>
        <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
        <context type="para">aaxx</context>
        <p type="paraX">kkll</p>
        <context type="para">aaxx</context>
        <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
        <context type="para">aaxx</context>
        <p type="paraX">kkll</p>
        <context type="para">aaxx</context>
        <p type="paraX">kkll</p>
    </section>


    <context type="para">aaxx</context>

    <s>jksjdl</s>
    <section>
        <p type="para">bbcc</p>
        <p type="paraX">kkll</p>
        <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
        <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
        <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
        <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
        <context type="para">aaxx</context>
        <p type="paraX">kkll</p>
        <context type="para">aaxx</context>
        <p type="paraX">kkll</p>
        <context type="para">aaxx</context>
        <p type="paraX">kkll</p>
        <context type="para">aaxx</context>
        <p type="paraX">kkll</p>
        <context type="para">aaxx</context>
        <p type="paraX">kkll</p>
    </section>
    <k>text</k>
    <section>
        <p type="para">bbcc</p>
        <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
        <p type="paraX">aaxx</p>
        <context type="para">aaxx</context>
        <p type="paraX">kkll</p>
        <p type="paraX">kkll</p>
        <context type="para">aaxx</context>
        <p type="paraX">kkll</p>
    </section>
    <context type="para">aaxx</context>
</doc>
```

Any idea how can I modify my templates to get the correct output?

Comment: What should happen with e.g. `<p type="para">bbcc</p> <p type="paraX">kkll</p><p type="paraX">aaxx</p><k>text</k><p type="paraX">kkll</p><p type="paraX">aaxx</p>`, what should happen in this case with the last two `para type="paraX"` elements?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, in the scenario you mentioned, para type="paraX" should copy to the output as it is. (without inside a <section element>).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified the requirements clearly enough to be certain of getting the code right, but for the supplied input, the following would work:

```
<xsl:template match="doc">
<doc>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="*" 
    group-starting-with="p[@type='para'] | *[not(self::p | self::context)]">
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="self::p">
      <section><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/></section>
     <xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
     </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</doc>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm sure your approach using sibling recursion can be made to work, but personally I find positional grouping with for-each-group much clearer and easier to debug.